# IS Zend Framework 2 work with PHP version 5.3.2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is Zend Framework 2 work with  PHP version 5.3.2?. During the skeleton application installation i got following message.Is this just a warning or it will cause any problem in future?

```
D:\web\Apache24\htdocs\zendsample>composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework
/skeleton-application D:\web\Apache24\htdocs\zendsample
Your version of PHP, 5.3.22, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perf
orm certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.
Installing zendframework/skeleton-application (2.4.11)
```

Comment: you will not be able to use recent zf2 versions with 5.3 and none of them with < 5.3.3, it does not support obsolete php versions.

Comment: Ok Got the point. I just installed successfully with the command "composer install --ignore-platform-reqs". It is better to update the PHP r8? before moving forward.

Comment: Most of zf2 will work on 5.3.23, may be with some subtle bugs. But some components will break. I recommend to update php straight to php 7. Last of the php 5 - 5.6 is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make thinks short :

With PHP 5.3 you'll not able to use [Traits](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.traits.php) and [new features php 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) wich is used in most of vendor plugin and the framework itself.

Usually it's strongly recommanded to upgrade your PHP version.

From this link [PHP version maintained](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) PHP 5.3 is no longer maintained since 2014. It's antique. You'll be face to security issues and no evolution of your code will be possible.

To answer your question :

- You'll not able to use traits
- You'll faceing security issues
- You'll not able to improve your code withe best practises (wich evolves permanently)
- your views can't use short version for echoing stuff `<?='toto'?>`
- All new features linked above are not supported with your version if it's used in the framework, you'll can't run the framework itself.
- **I recommend upgrade your version at least at 5.6 or 7 for a good longevity support**

EDIT : 5.5 to 5.6 because 5.5 no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

After getting this message i just upgraded my php to 5.5.

Comment: i just want to know that is there any problem will occur if i moved with 5.3?